# assign id to select box magento admin custom grid

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have custom grid on my magento admin panel where I want to add product id as a css id to every select box I have tried `'column_css_class' => 'id'` but this add class to every select box with id word not its value how can i do this

```
$this->addColumn('icon',
        array(
            'header'    => 'Icon',
            'width'     => '100px',
            'type'      => 'action',
            'getter'    => 'getId',
            'index'     => 'stores',
            'column_css_class' => 'id',
            'actions'   => array(

                array(
                    'caption' => 'Enable',
                    'url'     => array(
                    'base'=>'*/*/enable'
                    ),'field'   => 'id'
                    ),
                array(
                    'caption' => 'Disable',
                    'url'     => array(
                    'base'=>'*/*/disable'
                    ),
                    'field'     => 'id'
                )
            )
));
```

Comment: where are you calling this from? Do you have a product object ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a product object says $oProduct,
You can change your code so that instead of

`'column_css_class' => 'id'`

You would have:

`'column_css_class' => $oProduct->getId()`

Also using product id is not a good idea, use SKU instead.